# Failing to understand "i < number + 10" condition in javascript for loop

Tags: javascript

I'd like to ask a user to enter a number. Output should be ten numbers (starting with the number entered), that shows the numbers being even or odd. For example, if a user enters 3, then the output would show 3 is odd, 4 is even, 5 is odd, etc., all the way to 12 is even, and stops there (3 to 12 is ten numbers). I know the code below achieves this, but I'm failing to understand the "i < number + 10" condition. Please explain.

```
const number = Number(prompt("Enter the starting number:"));

for (let i = number; i < number + 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) {
    console.log(`${i} is even`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${i} is odd`);
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to run this loop starting from number entered by user and end after ten digit from there .

Comment: so number is "13" So you got `let i = 13; i< 13 + 10;`

Comment: You start the loop at number `i = number` or `i = 3` and you want it to run until `i` is less than `number + 10` or (`i < 13`)

Comment: `3 < 13`, `4 < 13`, `5 < 13`, ..., `13 < 13`

Comment: `let i = number;` do that on a piece of paper, write e.g. "i: 3". `i < number + 10` in this case is `i < 13`, so check that. If it works out, add a checkmark to the "i: 3" - your loop executed once. If it doesn't, end. `i++`, increase `i`, e.g. continue with writing "i: 4", repeat, until your condition fails. You should end up with a list of things on your paper. Look at which numbers you went over, and which have a checkmark, so they got executed. You'll probably understand then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
const number = Number(prompt("Enter the starting number:"));
```

That prompts the user to enter a number and it gets assigned to the constant, `number`. Let's say they enter `7`. Then you have:

```
for (let i = number; i < number + 10; i++) {
```

Substituting your `number` constant into that you get:

```
for (let i = 7; i < 7 + 10; i++) {
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
for (let i = 7; i < 17; i++) {
```